# How to append form inputs to a url and call that url?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a url and I want a user to fill a form and submit the form The submit action should then append the various inputs to that url and redirect the page. I'm new to jquery and I don't think that would be very helpful I also have very little knowl

Comment: Oh, wow... Didn't notice that part.... .....knowledge of php... Can anyone assist with this please?

Comment: Rather than list a set of requirements and expecting someone to write it for you, show evidence of the research carried out, the code you have implemented and the exact issue you are experiencing - please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

you can use form method as get and all values will be appended to the url

Answer (score 0):

So start with the form

```
<form method="get" action="page2.php">
  <input type="text" name="one">
  <input type="text" name="two">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

//page2.php
<?php
  $one = $_GET[ 'one' ];
  $two = $_GET[ 'two' ];
?>
```

You will notice when you submit the form that the values from the two inputs can be seen in the url.